# oracle sql how combine column string value

Tags: sql, oracle

i have records

```
id | key | string column
------------------------
1  | 1   | A
------------------------
1  | 1   | B
------------------------
1  | 1   | C
```

i want result like below

```
id | key | string column
------------------------
1  | 1   | A, B, C
------------------------
```

someone know how to do?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`listagg()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions101.htm#SQLRF30030):

```
select id, key, listagg(string, ', ') within group (order by string)
from t
group by id, key;
```